# Install composer dependencies while deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

I'm using Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my application as a **Single Docker Application**.

My Dockerfile does `composer install` while deploying, but I get a `Could not authenticate against github.com` error.

I use these lines in my `Dockerfile` to install my dependencies:

```
WORKDIR /www
RUN ["composer", "install", "-o"]
```

How would I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure composer inside your container with your key or something like that, remember that inside your container you're basically on another os and you don't have public keys etc.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try to install it from source rather than from git (as you don't have keys).

[try this](https://github.com/RobLoach/docker-composer):
`RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer` ()